# How to retrieve Node properties from Swift using Theo and Neo4j Database?

Tags: swift, xcode, neo4j, cypher

Below is my code snippet from my Swift Xcode project. I am currently developing an app in Xcode with Swift and I am attempting to use Neo4j as the backend for storing all the data etc.

When it comes to using Swift and Neo4j the only option is to use Theo to connect and communicate with a Neo4j database. You can do Cypher queries directly although it has proven to be quite difficult when I want to grab data from the Neo4j database and store it locally in a variable or an array in Swift.

My Code, bare in mind this is taken directly from the Neo4j Theo Swift example package, that you can find here - https://github.com/GraphStory/neo4j-ios

```
import UIKit
import Theo
import PackStream

class QueryViewController: UIViewController {

    var connectionConfig: ConnectionConfig?
    @IBOutlet weak var outputTextView: UITextView?

    //All of the User Interface Outlets, Buttons etc.
    @IBOutlet weak var createNodeButton: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet weak var fetchNodeButton: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet weak var runCypherButton: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet weak var runTransactionButton: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet weak var clientNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var clientYearBorn: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nodeInfo: UILabel!

    var query: String!
    var clientArray: [String] = []

    var clientID : Int = 0
    var clientName: String!
    var yearBorn: String!

    private var theo: BoltClient?
    private var lastNodeId: UInt64 = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        disableButtons()
        if let config = connectionConfig {
            do {
                self.theo = try BoltClient(
                    hostname: config.host,
                    port: config.port,
                    username: config.username,
                    password: config.password,
                    encrypted: true)
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.outputTextView?.text = "Failed during connection configuration"
                }
                return
            }

            guard let theo = self.theo else { return }

            log("Connecting...")

            let result = theo.connectSync()
            switch result {
            case .failure(_):
                log("Error while connecting")
            case .success(_):
                let result = theo.executeCypherSync("MATCH (n:ImpossibleNode) RETURN count(n) AS n")
                switch result {
                case let .failure(error):
                    log("Error while connecting: \(error)")
                case .success(_):
                    log("Connected")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                        self?.enableButtons()
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            outputTextView?.text = "Missing connection configuration"
        }
    }

    private func enableButtons() {
        createNodeButton?.isEnabled = true
        fetchNodeButton?.isEnabled = true
        runCypherButton?.isEnabled = true
        runTransactionButton?.isEnabled = true
    }

    private func disableButtons() {
        createNodeButton?.isEnabled = false
        fetchNodeButton?.isEnabled = false
        runCypherButton?.isEnabled = false
        runTransactionButton?.isEnabled = false
    }

    //Here we can create a Node to add to the Neo4j Database.
    @IBAction func createNodeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard let theo = self.theo else {
            log("Client not initialized yet")
            return
        }

    //Here we define some variables we wish to store within the node as Properties.
         clientName = clientNameField?.text
         yearBorn = clientYearBorn.text
         clientID = Int(lastNodeId)

         self.lastNodeId += 1

        let node = Node(label: "Client", properties:["id": clientID, "name": clientName, "yearBorn": yearBorn])

        let result = theo.createAndReturnNodeSync(node: node)
        switch result {
        case let .failure(error):
            log("Error while creating node: \(error)")
        case let .success(responseNode):
            log("Successfully created node: \(responseNode)")
            lastNodeId = responseNode.id!

            clientName = clientNameField?.text
            print("Added", clientName!, "to the Nexus")
            print(clientID)

        }
    }

    @IBAction func fetchNodeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard let theo = self.theo else {
            log("Client not initialized yet")
            return
        }

        theo.nodeBy(id: lastNodeId) { result in
            switch result {
            case let .failure(error):
                self.log("Error while reading fetched node with ID '\(self.lastNodeId)': \(error)")
            case let .success(responseNode):
                if let responseNode = responseNode {
                    self.log("Fetched node with ID \(self.lastNodeId): \(responseNode)")

                    //Here I am attempting to grab all the nodes labeled "Client" with the property name "Mr Davies"

                    let results = theo.executeCypherSync("MATCH (c:Client{name: 'Mr Davies'}) RETURN (c)")

                    //Here I am appending the results from the Cypher Query above to an array - clientArray
                    self.clientArray.append((results.value?.nodes.description)!)

                    //Finally here I am printing to the console the client array.
                    print(self.clientArray)
                } else {
                    self.log("Could not find node with ID \(self.lastNodeId)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func log(_ string: String) {
        print(string)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let text = self.outputTextView?.text ?? ""
            if text == "" {
                self.outputTextView?.text = string
            } else {
                self.outputTextView?.text = "\(string)\n\n\(text)"

            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func runCypherTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard let theo = self.theo else {
            log("Client not initialized yet")
            return
        }

        let result = theo.executeCypherSync("MATCH (c:Client) RETURN count(c) AS num")
        switch result {
        case let .failure(error):
            log("Error while getting cypher results: \(error)")
        case let .success(queryResult):
            if let intNum = queryResult.rows[0]["num"] as? UInt64 {
                log("Asked via Cypher how many nodes there are with label Client. Answer: \(intNum)")

            } else {
                log("Got unexpected answer back")

            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func runTransactionTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        do {
            try theo?.executeAsTransaction(transactionBlock: { (tx) in
                let query = "CREATE (C:Client { name: {name} } )"
                self.theo?.executeCypherSync(query, params: ["prop": "name"])
                self.theo?.executeCypherSync(query, params: ["prop": "yearborn"])

            })
        } catch {
            log("Error while executing transaction: \(error)")
            return
        }

        log("Transaction completed successfully")
    }
}
```

My aim with this app is to grab all nodes labeled "Client" and then store the properties of said nodes into either 1 or more local arrays within Swift. Then I can go about manipulating the data, within the "fetchNodeTapped" function I have commented the code. You can see that I print the array contents out to the console and here is what I get:

> Fetched node with ID 260: Theo.Node ["[244: Theo.Node, 229: Theo.Node,
>   154: Theo.Node, 230: Theo.Node, 215: Theo.Node, 226: Theo.Node, 249:
>   Theo.Node, 177: Theo.Node, 277: Theo.Node, 214: Theo.Node, 278:
>   Theo.Node, 222: Theo.Node, 285: Theo.Node, 206: Theo.Node, 158:
>   Theo.Node, 258: Theo.Node, 217: Theo.Node, 167: Theo.Node, 176:
>   Theo.Node, 223: Theo.Node, 153: Theo.Node, 168: Theo.Node, 266:
>   Theo.Node, 228: Theo.Node, 169: Theo.Node, 220: Theo.Node, 247:
>   Theo.Node, 150: Theo.Node, 284: Theo.Node, 216: Theo.Node, 156:
>   Theo.Node, 272: Theo.Node, 243: Theo.Node, 255: Theo.Node, 264:
>   Theo.Node, 268: Theo.Node, 205: Theo.Node, 273: Theo.Node, 320:
>   Theo.Node, 175: Theo.Node, 151: Theo.Node, 257: Theo.Node, 225:
>   Theo.Node, 172: Theo.Node, 270: Theo.Node, 274: Theo.Node, 246:
>   Theo.Node, 224: Theo.Node, 245: Theo.Node, 283: Theo.Node, 248:
>   Theo.Node, 170: Theo.Node, 318: Theo.Node, 160: Theo.Node, 218:
>   Theo.Node, 152: Theo.Node, 184: Theo.Node, 256: Theo.Node, 260:
>   Theo.Node, 231: Theo.Node, 173: Theo.Node, 171: Theo.Node, 149:
>   Theo.Node, 157: Theo.Node, 161: Theo.Node, 221: Theo.Node, 271:
>   Theo.Node, 227: Theo.Node, 275: Theo.Node, 276: Theo.Node, 279:
>   Theo.Node, 155: Theo.Node, 183: Theo.Node, 219: Theo.Node, 265:
>   Theo.Node, 267: Theo.Node, 162: Theo.Node, 250: Theo.Node, 263:
>   Theo.Node, 269: Theo.Node, 319: Theo.Node, 159: Theo.Node]"]

Here you can see that my function is storing every "Mr Davies" Node and when I print it to the console it prints out each Nodes ID "Theo.Node, 319: for instance. I would like to access specific properties of each node so I can retrieve all the properties from the database(name, yearBorn etc)and then store those properties locally as I stated above.

If anyone can help with this it would be greatly appreciated, if you have any further questions about my question then fire away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question completely, but you can use the [keys()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-keys) function to return the property names of nodes or relationships. For example:

Creating a sample node:

```
CREATE (:Node {firstname : "Jon", lastname : "Doe", age : 20})
```

Then:

```
MATCH (node:Node)
RETURN keys(node)
```

The output will be:

```
╒══════════════════════════════╕
│"keys(node)"                  │
╞══════════════════════════════╡
│["firstname","age","lastname"]│
└──────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have tested using this line of code:

let results = theo.executeCypherSync("MATCH (c:Client) RETURN keys (c)")
print(results)

However I get an error of "Index out of range" which subsequently crashes the app in simulator.

Comment: @LukeIreton The Index out of range errors is probably not related to the Cypher execution. It should be related to the rest of your logic.

Comment: Okay nice, I have managed to get up to this point


 self.clientArray.append(results.value?.nodes.keys)
                    print(self.clientArray)

however now I am stopped with a conversion error, "Cannot convert value of type 'LazyMapCollection<[UInt64 : Node], UInt64>?' to expected argument type 'Node'" any thoughts on this? I am using a String Array to store the keys.

Comment: @LukeIreton Unfortunately I'n not a Swift programmer, sorry.

Comment: Okay well thank you for the help, I think using keys is the right direction to be heading in.

Comment: @LukeIreton you are welcome! I think that is a good idea to ask a new question about this specific problem and tag it with [swift]. Also, if this  answer has solved your main problem I suggest you to consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!